# Laravel Pagination is suddenly Bootstrap CSS

Tags: laravel

I use `Laravel 8` with `TailwindCSS`. Pagination always worked well. And from one moment to the other the Pagination style is broken. I inspect the source code from the pagination and I found out that the classes are BootstrapCSS and not TailwindCSS. How can this be?

**What did I do just before?**

I had installed the package `Laravelist/Comment` shortly before. And since then the pagination is BootstrapCSS instead of TailwindCSS.

**What have I already done to fix the error?**

- `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php dump-autoload -o`
- Checked the `AppServiceProvider` method `boot()` is empty.
- The blade file also contains the default link: `{{ $posts->links() }}`
- Then I checked out of my feature branch in development and even there the links are no longer correct.

#### Question:

How can I get back the **TailwindCSS** pagination?

Comment: try and uninstall `Laravelist/Comment` and check if pagination work correctly. If it does not, then problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Idk the why you get the problem out of a sudden, you could try calling `dd(\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::$defaultView);` somewhere it should give you `"pagination::tailwind"`

Comment: Laravelist/Commt is cousin this, there is a configuration see the source code here: https://github.com/laravelista/comments/blob/fcbbadad6e080eb297d9ea216fb8d8825bbcf50a/src/ServiceProvider.php#L90

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. Thanks to @RolandStarke. The package overwrites something in the vendor folder. As a result, it was not possible for me to resolve the error with a branch change. The only solution was to delete the vendor folder completely and reinitiate it with composer install. I find the package `laravista/comment` strange and will not use it in any case. So now I'm building my own nested comment system.